# How to use the Weierstrass M-Test to bound this series from above?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{z^k}{z^k+1}\right)$ on $\overline{D}[0,r]$ for $0\leq r<1$ and I know that I can use the Weierstrass M-Test to do so, but I do not know how to bound this series from above. How does knowing that we are only looking at a specific region help us?

Comment: We need to find a positive sequence $M_k$ such that (i) $\sum_{k \geq 0} M_k$ converges and (ii) $\left\vert \frac{z^k}{z^k + 1} \right\vert \leq M_k$ for all $z \in \bar D[0,r]$ and for all $k \geq 0$. The fact that we're looking at $\bar D[0,r]$ appears in part (ii). Is this enough for you to start playing around?

Comment: You might like to start with a warmup example: $\sum_{k \geq 0} z^k$ on $\bar D[0,r]$, with $0 \leq r  < 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In $\overline {D} (0,r),$

$$\left | \frac{z^k}{1+z^k}\right | \le \frac{r^k}{1-r^k}.$$